# How to pass data from Sidemenu to other Page while navigating

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

so basically i have two type of users Teacher and Student so how am is supposed to show different profile screens based on the user type.

my Sidemenu is in app.components.ts

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the guide how to ask questions :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**By assuming that you want to navigate to the respective pages,**
You can do it using router.navigate function from the component or using routerLink from HTML itself.
We will create separate folders for teacher and student and components and respective CSS and HTML files.

Step 1) We will add routings of the above components inside app-module.routings.ts file, which we have to create manually in app folder of our application

### app-module.routings.ts

```
import { TeacherComponent } from './teacher/teacher.component';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/teacher', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'teacher', component: TeacherComponent },
  { path: 'student', component: StudentComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Step 2) Add navigation logic

### app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Changing the navigation';
  currentPage = 'teacher';
  constructor(private router: Router){}

  navigatePageTo(page) {
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.router.navigate([page]);
  }
}
```

Step 3) Add the respective links

### app.component.html

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a (click)="navigatePageTo('teacher')" [class.activeLink]="currentPage === 'teacher'">Teacher</a>
  <a (click)="navigatePageTo('student')" [class.activeLink]="currentPage === 'student'">Student</a>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You can check the [Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-54417878)

Hope this is what you were expecting.